# SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)

Tags: javascript, firefox, syntax, arrow-functions

Such code will generate an error:

```
if(hr>t1[0]||(hr==t1[0]&&min=>t1[1]) && hr<t2[0]||(hr==t2[0]&&min<t2[1]))
```

The error:

**`SyntaxError:`** invalid *arrow-function* arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)

What does it mean, how did it happen? Google searches for this error are desperately useless.

**Edit:**

Seems to be caused by using `=>` instead of `>=`. But I'm still curious why is the error formulated like this, and what the arrow function is supposed to be.

**Edit 2.**

First, I didn't realise that this could actually be browser specific issue. Also, I didn't realise that these days, people use JS in other places than browser context. So, to make that clear, my browser is Mozilla Firefox 25.0.1.

Comment: You're using coffeescript, not javascript

Comment: `=>` should be `>=` ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error

Comment: FYI, arrow functions are part of ES6 and seem to be supported in FF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions.

Comment: @Eric No, I'm using regular javascript.

Comment: What browser / js engine?

Comment: Was your intention to use arrow function or just a comparison?

Comment: @PSL: *"But I'm still curious [...] what the arrow function is supposed to be."* I assume the latter.

Comment: @FelixKling hmm go it. I have reverted my close vote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=>` should be `>=` (more than or equal)

---

An arrow-function is a coffeescript (and [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)!) feature - this:

```
f = x => this.y * x
```

Is equivalent to:

```
f = function(x) {
    return this.y * x;
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: It's also an ES6 feature!

Comment: And firefox supports this in normal JS?